# Async operations in MVC 4 with progress visualization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, async-await

I'm using DevExpress Controls in my MVC 4 application.

I now want to use their PopupControl to display the progress of an asynchronous operation (mostly FTP / Http calls, that could take quite some time).

For this question, any progressbar (not neccessarily within a PopupControl) will do just fine.

As I'm aware, in MVC 3 you've used AsyncControllers for that, but to my understanding they're deprecated with MVC 4 (.NET 4.5). Is there any tutorial out there on how to accomplish my task?

Comment: I'm not sure about the PopupControl, but to the other half of your question, this is how asynchronous controllers are done in MVC 4 with .NET 4.5 http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: @Mikhail Because it's not primarily related to DevExpress. Why should I bother them with questions about the framework and not their products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard techniques to get process of the async operations. Once results are available, display them with a corrsponding HTML element (PopupControl, ProgressBar, etc.).

Check the [How to display progress information about server-side callback processing](http://www.devexpress.com/example=E4244) sample in the DevExpress forum.

Comment: This solution is not good because it block the main thread. Now you have possibility to use async await to detach it from thread.